# Iterate through a vue bootstrap modal in a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a vue bootstrap modal within a v-for and I want replace the 1 in 'v-b-modal.modal-1' and 'modal-1' with the index, which I can print within the loop as {{ index }} but I can't figure out how I would add this to the end of each identifier.

```
<div v-for="(movie, index, i) in movies">
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal</b-button>
  <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the question reference whether you can apply modifiers dynamically, the **No** you can't do it, it should be static.

But as your question relates to Bootstrap modal, I have read this usage while researching solution.

I believe you can do this by passing the modifier as value which behaves as `id` , and since the value is JS expression you can manipulate it dynamically.

`<b-button v-b-modal="'modal-1'">Launch demo modal</b-button>`

```
<div v-for="(movie, index, i) in movies">
  <b-button v-b-modal="'modal-1'">Launch demo modal</b-button>
  <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: To use the index it would be ```v-b-modal="`modal-${index}`"``` and ```:id="`modal-${index}`"```